# Select a DataRow in a DataGridView after creating new row

Tags: c#, postgresql, datagridview

I use a PostgreSQL view to display data in a `DataGridView`:

```
dataSource = new BindingSource();
dataSource.DataSource = Program.DB.GetView(dbView);  // returns a DataTable
dgData.DataSource = dataSource;
```

Now, after I added a record using a PostgreSQL function, I refresh the data in the grid (I don't call `Rows.Add()` on the `DataGridView`:

```
protected void RefreshData() {
    dataSource.DataSource = Program.DB.GetView(dbView);
}
```

The insertion function of PostgreSQL returns the ID of the inserted row, so I know the ID (which is primary key) and want to set `Selected` to `true` in the `DataGridView`. The row can be anywhere in the set, because the view is sorted by name, not ID. I reckon I could do that by cycling over all rows and set the `Selected` when I found it, but this could become slow on large datasets.

Is there a way to somehow bind the rows of the datasource to the datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler to the `ListChanged` event:

```
dataSource.ListChanged += dataSource_ListChanged;
```

Here is the event handler definition:

```
void dataSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgData.Rows.Count > 0)
        dgData.CurrentCell = dgData.Rows[e.NewIndex].Cells[0];
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

As I also suggested in the comments, maybe you should not repopulate the data source on each insert (or update). To demonstrate my point, I'll post a code sample which uses a `DataGridView`, 2 `TextBoxes` and 2 `Button`s (for insert and update) and a `SqlDataAdapter`. The SQL table has 2 columns (`id` and `value`).

Here's the code (I didn't cover the deletion):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static BindingSource dataSource;
    static string dbView = "default";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgData.MultiSelect = false;
        dataSource = new BindingSource();
        dataSource.ListChanged += dataSource_ListChanged;
        RefreshData();
        dgData.DataSource = dataSource;
        dgData.Sort(dgData.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }

    void dataSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgData.Rows.Count > 0)
            dgData.CurrentCell = dgData.Rows[e.NewIndex].Cells[0];
    }

    protected void RefreshData()
    {
        dataSource.DataSource = DB.GetView(dbView);
    }

    private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DB.Insert(textBox1.Text);
        RefreshData();
    }

    private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DB.UpdateRandomRow(textBox2.Text);
        RefreshData();
    }
}

class DB
{
    static DataTable dt;
    static string conStr = "yourConnectionString";
    static SqlDataAdapter _adapter;
    static Random r = new Random(10);

    public static SqlDataAdapter CreateSqlDataAdapter(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        _adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

        _adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM test", connection);
        _adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO test (value) " +
            "VALUES (@value)", connection);
        _adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(
            "UPDATE test SET [value] = @value " +
            "WHERE id = @id", connection);
        _adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@value",
            SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "value");
        _adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@id",
            SqlDbType.Int, 4, "id").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
        _adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@value",
            SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "value").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;

        return _adapter;
    }

    // random update, to demonstrate dynamic
    // repositioning
    public static DataTable UpdateRandomRow(string value)
    {
        var currentRandom = r.Next(dt.Rows.Count);
        dt.Rows[currentRandom].SetField<string>(1, value);
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            con.Open();
            _adapter = CreateSqlDataAdapter(con);
            _adapter.Update(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    internal static DataTable GetView(string dbView)
    {
        if (dt == null)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                con.Open();
                _adapter = CreateSqlDataAdapter(con);
                _adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }

    internal static void Insert(string value)
    {
        if (dt == null)
            GetView("");
        var dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[1] = value;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            con.Open();
            _adapter = CreateSqlDataAdapter(con);
            _adapter.Update(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

If you test it, you'll see that the request from your question is satisfied for both insert and update. Also, please note the performance improvement, as the data table is not recreated on each operation.

Comment: `e.NewIndex` is -1 in the handler. Perhaps because I refresh the entire dataSource.

Comment: Ok, I incorrectly assumed that you update the `DataTable`. Let's have another persepctive, you said: _When I have inserted a new row, I know the ID (which is primary key)_. Do you store it in some variable? Could you update your question with more details about this aspect?

Comment: Updated my question; the ID is returned by the PostgreSQL function. (or 0 when it failed, but that's outside the scope of this question)

Comment: Maybe you should not refresh the entire `dataSource`. Especially if this is not a fast changing data source. I think you should be considering a persistence mechanism for the `DataTable`. I'll add a simple sample in my answer to demonstrate my point.